# PHP declaration of class must be compatible with abstract class

Tags: php

So we're running software (not written by us) on our server and we started getting errors emailed to us that look like this:

Could not instantiate the 'multilingual' module because of the following error. Stack traces are unfortunately not available for this type of error:

Error Message:

> Declaration of CMH\Multilingual\Multilingual::getData($project_id,
> $record) must be compatible with
> ExternalModules\AbstractExternalModule::getData($projectId, $recordId,
> $eventId = '', $format = 'array') File:
> modules/multilingual_v1.9.8/Multilingual.php Line: 486

However, we have another server that runs it just fine. So as to not have to delve into the code for this software, I've created a simple PHP program that does the same thing: fails on one server, works on the other.

```
class AbstractClass {
    public function DoThisThing($var1, $var2, $var3 = "")
    {
        echo "DO THIS THING!";
    }
}

class ConcreteClass extends AbstractClass {
    public function DoThisThing($var1, $var2) {
        echo "DID THIS THING!";
    }
}

$thisThing = new ConcreteClass();
$thisThing->DoThisThing(1, 2);
```

The server that this fails on runs PHP 7.4.14 and the server it works on is 7.3.20. From what I can tell, since $var3 is optional in AbstractClass, it should be fine right? Or do the signatures have to be exact? Is this something introduced in PHP 7.4 or is there a setting I can change?

Comment: It is failing (or at least warning) on 7.3.20 as well: https://3v4l.org/e5NuZ you might wanna read up on [Variance](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.variance.php) though. Quote: `As of PHP 7.4.0, full covariance and contravariance support was added.`

Comment: Interesting, I don't get a warning on my server. Must be set somewhere not to report them. So there is no way to turn that error off? If not, I'll have to find out how to contact the author of the software...

Comment: The example code doesn't fail for 7.4.14, it warns just like 7.3.20. Only in PHP 8 does it throw a fatal error (see @ArSeN's linked fiddle). So there must be some custom handling involved in that library's source code to make it fail.

Comment: Y'all know what? Apache uses PHP 7.4.14, but looking at the box the version of PHP in the path is 8.0.1. This piece of software runs in Apache, but has a part that is called in a cron job... using the version of php in the path which must have just been upgraded. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Well, seeing a warning not as a fail is a very PHP-ish thing to say ;) But I get your point, it warns then. Glad we could help!

Answer (score 0):

With PHP 7.4, you do have to match the arguments. This would be the correct way to write this code:

```
<?php

class AbstractClass {
    public function DoThisThing($var1, $var2, $var3 = "")
    {
        echo "DO THIS THING!";
    }
}

class ConcreteClass extends AbstractClass {
    public function DoThisThing($var1, $var2, $var3 = "") {
        echo "DID THIS THING!";
    }
}

$thisThing = new ConcreteClass();
$thisThing->DoThisThing(1, 2);
```